# Soffits are dripping brownish water

Tags: soffit

I have a new home and noticed brownish water dripping from the soffits. They overhang 16". The house has a metal roof with ice and water shield and insulated with spray foam insulation. I was told that soffit vents were not necessary with this type of insulation.

Comment: Where is the spray foam insulation?  On the underside of the roof?  And is this an house with a attic?

Comment: Voting to close. Details are lacking and OP hasn't been back.

Answer (score 2):

Soffit vents are *always* better than no vents.  THere's a volume of air in your attic between the attic floor & the roof.  You don't make it clear where the foamed insulation is.  If it's on the inside of the roof it may keep the attic temp a bit more stable but is otherwise a waste of money.

If you don't have a ridge-vent or other roof vents (or large gable-end windows) there's no circulation in the attic.  Sooner or later the cooler air will migrate downwards, find the soffits,  dump water there (cooler air holds less water vapor than warmer); that may be the main source of your drips.  I would in any case go into the attic to see where the water's coming from.